# How can I split  a 1-dimensional array to multiple arrays?

Tags: java

This is my question please give me some hint or idea on how am I going to split 1 dimensional array to multidimensional array if it see a special character e.g - or /?

Example data:

```
input:
array1 [] = { "name1-name2", "box1-box2" }
output:
array2 [][]= { {"name1"}, {"name2"}, {"box1"}, {"box2"}}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the input you expect and the output you want?

Comment: How can you split it into something bigger? This question really doesn't make any sense.

Comment: edit your message to post an example

Comment: by writing a function with some code that will split the array when it sees a special character.

Comment: For example array1 []= {name1-name2,box1-box2,} and it will be like this array2[][]={{name1},{name2},{box1},{box2}}. Hope this help

Answer (score 1):

Without having more detail... you want to iterate over the original array, most likely calling `split` to parse based on the 'special character', and insert the values into a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

You could work on improving your question but i think i get the gist. Try this:

```
String[][] multi = new String[myArray.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
    multi[i] = myArray[i].split("/");
}
```

It's untested so you may have to work it a little

Answer (score 0):

Use the [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method like so:

```
String[] array=myString.split("-");
```